# How to turn csv file data into a list WITHOUT the 'import csv'

Tags: csv

So what I'm trying to do is, I'm trying to read the data in the CSV file into the empty lists I've defined at the top.

How can I do
   this without the 'csv import'

```
    L = []
    F = []
    G = []
    A = []

        class client ():


        fh = open('fit_clinic_20.csv', 'r')

        for line in fh:
            data = fh.readlines()
            L, F, G, A = fh.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```
L = []
F = []
G = []
A = []


fh = open('fit_clinic_20.csv', 'r')

# first: you read lines
data = fh.readlines()

for line in data:
    # you split every line into values
    L_value, F_value, G_value, A_value = line.split(',')

    # you append values to lists
    L.append(L_value)
    F.append(F_value)
    G.append(G_value)
    A.append(A_value)
```

Surely, there are more compact ways to do this, but I think that this way is well understandable.